# How to apply regular expression on spark for only number extraction on spark

Tags: regex, apache-spark

I am trying to do regular expression on my data set.
my issue is i want replace alphabets with empty.

i have tried following code

```
   val test_reg = xmlData.withColumn("volume",regexp_replace($"trans_volume", "[^0-9]", ""))
```

but if my input contains something other than alpahabets , that also replacing with empty

```
  lets say my input contains 34m89 it replaces as 3489 which is perfectly fine.
  but if my input contains 34.78 that is getting replaced as 3478 which actually should not happen.
```

can some help me how to resolve my issue ?

Answer (score -1):

```
val test_reg = xmlData.withColumn("volume",regexp_replace($"trans_volume", "[^0-9].", ""))
```

probably you should add **.** to your regex **"[^0-9]."**